# Black background color tooltips in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: background, tooltip

I have encountered a problem, and it is a black background color tooltips in Eclipse Oxygen. I have googled this problem, but I only found a solution for linux. I am using eclipse in Windows. Please help me solve this problem. It really annoys me.

[image]

Comment: On a side note, what is the theme and color and font theme you're using???

Comment: i had similar issue. on eclipse.neon under centos7 i had yellow text with white background. my workaround was to change the eclipse theme from "GTK" to "high contrast" and it fixed the issue. (FYI apparently in eclipse.oxygen there is a setting for the tooltip background color).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Go to Window->Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts. Type in the filter "javadoc". Select Javadoc background and click on Edit. You can select the background color there

Comment: I have to restart Eclipse to see changes.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what solved the problem for me on Eclipse 2018-19 (SimRel). I did it by changing the theme from the eclipse menu by going to :

Window -> Preferences -> Clicking on the Appearance option -> Changing the Colors and Fonts to something else.

For me, I had to change it from the reduced palette to the windows default.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Workspace and import the projects again . Worked fine for me .
I faced the issue on Mac , Eclipse Oxygen . I tried adding the Darkest Color theme and since then this problem started . I changed the workspace and reimported my projects again .

Comment: Yes, this works for me. I am using C/C++ and there is no such thing as background via filtering search as javadoc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to window in menu bar->preferences->general->appearance->colors and fonts-> type the javadoc in the filter box

Answer (score 0):

Preferences => C/C++ => Editor =>
"Appearance color options" : "Source hover background" (set color)